# Topological manifolds that admit no smooth structure

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Can anyone offer an intuitive description of a 
[topological manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_manifold) that admits no [smooth structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_structure)?
I know they exist, but am unsure if there is any path to some level of understanding aside from total immersion in the original papers.